# how to make a plot to show start and end days

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101), AEDECOD = c("Diarrhoea", 
"Vitreous floaters", "Musculoskeletal pain", "Diarrhoea", "Decreased appetite", 
"Fatigue"), AESTDY = structure(c(101, 74, 65, 2, 33, 27), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    AEENDY = structure(c(105, 99, NA, 5, NA, NA), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to make a plot that looks like following:

[image]

Sorry the the blurry plot. This is the closest one that I can find. What someone give me some guidance on how to make such plot?

Thanks.

Comment: How should we treat the NA values?
What does AESTDY mean regarding the start day?

Comment: AESTDY is the start point, and AEENDY is the end day. I think in the sample plot, they treat the one with start point but no end point with a triangle for start point, but no line connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot2, using Unicode's black "left pointer" and "right pointer" characters for the start and end arrows.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = AEDECOD, yend = AEDECOD, x = AESTDY, xend = AEENDY)) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = AESTDY), shape = "\u25BA") + 
    geom_point(aes(x = AEENDY), shape = "\u25C4") +
    geom_segment()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started.
There are issues about what to do with or how to interpret NAs - this approach just ignores them - you do not get a line.
Start days are indicated by a point.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("DY"), ~ as.numeric(str_extract(.x, "\\d+"))))

ggplot(df1)+
  geom_segment(aes(y = AEDECOD, yend = AEDECOD, x = AESTDY, xend = AEENDY))+
    geom_point(data = filter(df1, is.na(AEENDY)),  aes(y = AEDECOD, x = AESTDY))
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to keep those records with start day, sth that looks like the example plot? I was able to plot the graph like yours, but can not add the start and end point. do you think I should overlay a dot plot? Not sure how to do that.

Comment: OK start days now included.